# Properties of the vector space $V^-$ defined by "refusing" to multiply the complex vector space $V$ by anything other than real scalars.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I$\def\nc#1#2{\newcommand{#1}{#2}}\nc{\vm}{V^-\!}\nc{\v}{V}\nc{\f}{\mathbb{F}}\nc{\fn}{\f^n\!}$ am reading "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" by Halmos and several times he mentions the space denoted by $\vm$ which, for any complex vector space $\v$ of dimension $n$, is found by only multiplying vectors in $\v$ by real scalars.

My question is two fold.

An exercise asks the dimension of this vector space $\vm$. I figure that the basis for $\v$ will be the same as the basis for $\vm$ so the dimension must be $n$. I also suppose an isomorphism can be established with $\fn$ which allows us to take $\fn$ as a real vector space with dimension $n$. Is this reasoning correct?

My second question asks why this vector space $\vm$ could be considered important. I have a feeling it is more than a contrived example. Does anyone have any input?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the dimension of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Jonas I can reason (perhaps incorrectly) that the dimension should be $1$ following the steps in my post. Intuitivly, I would say that the dimension should be $2$ but I don't know of any reason why that would be true. Not surprisingly, I can't conceptualize the problem very well.

Comment: You can directly check.  $\{1\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb C$, but does it work for $\mathbb R$?  The set $\{a\cdot 1:a\in\mathbb R\}$ doesn't cover all complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a $\Bbb C$-vector space with $\Bbb C$-basis
$$
\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}
$$
Then for every $v\in V$ there exist unique $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n\in\Bbb C$ such that
$$
v=\alpha_1\cdot v_1+\dotsb+\alpha_n\cdot v_n
$$
But now there are unique $a_k,b_k\in\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha_k=a_k+ib_k$. Hence for every $v\in V$ there exist unique $a_1,\dotsc,a_n,b_1,\dotsc,b_n\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$
v=a_1\cdot v_1+\dotsb+a_n\cdot v_n+b_1\cdot iv_1+\dotsb+b_n\cdot iv_n\tag{1}
$$
Can you use equation (1) to find a basis (and hence compute the dimension) of $V^-$?

Comment: So the basis would be the collection of all the $a_j$ and $b_j\!$? The dimension must be $2n$.

Comment: The basis is not the $a_j$'s and $b_j$'s. The basis is $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n,i\cdot v_1,\dotsc,i\cdot v_n\}$.

Comment: Of course, I typed without thinking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

We will have 
$$\dim V^-=2\dim V$$ we can think of this as $$[V^-:\mathbb{R}]=[V:\mathbb{C}][\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]$$
The example is not contrived since this situation occurs all the time in algebra and representation theory.